# Set different views (list, thumbnail) for different folders?

Tags: directory, thumbnails, previews

As per the title, is it possible to set different types of views for each individual folders in the GUI ?

Changing the setting in one folder changes the view in all of them.

I'm switching from windows to Ubuntu (18.04.1 LTS) so I'm not fully accustomed  yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot permanently set a specific view for a specific folder in in the default file manager of Ubuntu 18.04, Files. Files will not remember settings on a per-folder basis.

At the moment you have a folder open, you can set different views for that particular Files window. It won't affect other open windows.

Each time you open a new Files window, it will adopt the view settings of your most recent setting. With respect to the size of the window, it will default to the window size of the last closed window of the previous setting (i.e., close all windows, the size of the last one you closed is used next time you open a window.)

*Edit 2021-01-14*: In Files 3.38 (Ubuntu 20.10), you can set different views in different windows. The view is not remembered on a per folder base. It is set for the current window without affecting the views in other windows.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's really too bad. I was hoping there would be more personalization options in Linux. Take control of your computer and all that.

Comment: Other file managers such as nemo (cinnamon desktop) and I guess caja (Mate desktop) remember views on a per folder basis. Disappointing as this anwer may be, please accept if it answers your current question.

Comment: I am confident Nautilus also have remembered viewing modes per folder in Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity. (Did not need to "set" anything, it just so happened; whenever I returned to my documents folder, it opened in list view, while my media folder always have opened with thumbnails.) I have found this question because I wanted to ask the same thing; I have recently updated to 20.04 with gnome. I wanted to ask: where has this feature gone?

Comment: Now, in 20.10, nautilus allows for different views in different windows. It is not "remembered" per folder, but set within the current window only.

Answer (score 0):

View in a single "Files" tab is the same. You can right-click on the folder and open the folder in "New Tab" or "New Window", and change its default view from the top left bar. Then both the windows will have different views, but they will remain till those windows are open. I hope it helps with your problem